# Redirect not logged in users if they are on a specific page and category

Tags: template-redirect

Following code is working fine for pages but how to add category id as well with pages in the following code.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

  if ( is_user_logged_in() || ! is_page() ) return;

  $restricted = array( 250, 253 ); // all your restricted pages

  if ( in_array( get_queried_object_id(), $restricted ) ) {
    wp_redirect( site_url( '/user-registration' ) ); 
    exit();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you actual code you can see this:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() || ! is_page() ) return;
```

This code does this: if user is logged in or **is not in a page**, then return/do nothing. You need to remove `! is_page()`:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;

    $restricted = array( 250, 253 ); // all your restricted pages

    if ( in_array( get_queried_object_id(), $restricted ) ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/user-registration' ) ); 
        exit();
    }

});
```

Alternatively you can leave `is_page()` and add also the check for [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category) as your needs.